# Plot bars starting from x axis not equal to 0 and extend to both sides

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

Suppose my data values are

```
  x <- c(30,50,70,120,150)
```

I want them in horizontal format (horiz=T).
Now My y axis position is in x=100 and I want bars to start from x=100, not from 0, and it should extend to left and right sides 
What to do?

```
x=c(30,50,70,120,150)
barplot(x,horiz=T)
axis(2,pos=100)
```

but this starts from zero and extends to 30, 50,70,120 etc . What I want is the bars should start from x=100 and extends left side for 30,50,70 and extends right side for 100+ values

Comment: x=c(30,50,70,120,150)
barplot(x,horiz=T)
axis(2,pos=100)

but this satrts from zero and extends to 30, 50,70,120 etc . 

What I want is the bars should start from x=100 and extends left side for 30,50,70 and extends right side for 100+ values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below example:

```
#data
x <- c(30,50,70,120,150)

#if less than 100 then plot to the left, ie: negaitve.
plot_x <- ifelse(x<100,x*-1,x)

#plot no x axis
barplot(plot_x,horiz=T,axes = FALSE,xlim=c(-200,200))

#add x and y axis
axis(1,at=seq(-100,100,50),
     labels = seq(0,200,50))
axis(2,pos=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `ggplot` solution:

```
x <- c(30,50,70,120,150)
x_100 <- data.frame(x=seq_along(x),y=x-100)
y_br <- seq(-75,50,25)

ggplot(x_100,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
   coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=y_br,labels=y_br+100)
```

The data must go to a data frame for `ggplot`. I subtract 100 from the data and later use `scale_y_continuous` to put the labels back to the "original" values.

In `ggplot`, the bar plot is plotted with vertical bars. `coord_flip` is used to interchange x- and y-axis, which leads to horizontal bars.

[image]